# Get the DataGridRow on MouseRightButtonUp event. - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to get the datagridrow of a datagrid when user right click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected row you need to add SelectionChange event

```
 private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   var rowview = dataGrid1.SelectedItem ;
     if (rowview != null)
     {
       //your code
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply.
Actually I wanted the Right click event. But still I can check it now in the above method.
Once again thanks.